# Find numbers within content and reformat them

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string, formatting

There's a lot of questions about formatting to 2 decimal places, but I've only found instances where they use `.val()`.  How do you do it if the number is a string pulled from `.html()`?

I have a table with some prices in it. Those prices are given to me as strings in to varying decimal places, e.g. $100.5, $59.95, $0.

I need each number to be to 2 decimal places, e.g. $100.50, $59.95, $0.00.

There might also be a £ instead of the $ in some cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are going for:

```
$("#mytable").find("td").each(function () {
    var content = this.innerHTML;
    content = content.replace(/\$(\d*(?:\.\d*)?)/g, function (m1, m2) {
        return "$" + parseFloat(m2).toFixed(2);
    });
    this.innerHTML = content;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QYexT/)

This will replace any finding of a dollar sign with a number following it and then make that number fixed to two decimals and replace it.

---

Based on your comment, to allow for £ as well as $, try this in place of the above:

```
content = content.replace(/([£$])(\d*(?:\.\d*)?)/g, function (m0, m1, m2) {
    return m1 +""+ parseFloat(m2).toFixed(2);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QYexT/1/)

It catches for `[£$]` (one of either symbol) and puts that in the first capture group which it passes to the function as `m1` the first group is the entire match which we don't want really, we are taking it in pieces.

---

Based on your second comment, if you added a `currency` class to your `td`'s that you have currency within and you only want a formatted number within it and don't want to touch the currency symbols, try this:

```
$("td.currency").each(function () {
    var content = this.innerHTML;
    content = content.replace(/(\d+(?:\.\d*)?)/g, function (m1, m2) {
        return parseFloat(m2).toFixed(2);
    });
    this.innerHTML = content;
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/QYexT/2/)

Notice only the numbers within the `.currency` cells got updated.

Comment: This is exactly what I was going for, thanks!  Just to add further complexity, would there be a way around this if the currency wasn't always dollars?  Say sometimes it's £ if the content was on an international site?

Comment: Maybe if the `<td>`'s that have the prices had a class `.currency` then I could target them without having to find the $ sign?  Not sure how to do that though...

Answer (score 0):

If you able to use other Java script I love "sugarjs" http://sugarjs.com/features#number

and you able to use code like this

```
(125.425).round(2);
>125.43
(125.425).round(-2);
>100
(4235000).format();
>"4,235,000"
(50).pad(5);
>"00050"
(23).ordinalize();
>"23rd"
```